# Finding a dual basis given another basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a vector space with dimension $n$ and basis $\{p_1, \cdots , p_n \}$. Suppose
$\{ q_1, \cdots , q_n \}$ is a dual basis of $\{p_1, \cdots , p_n \}$. How can
I find the dual basis $\{r_1, \cdots , r_n \}$ of 
$\{p_1 + p_2, p_2, p_3, \cdots , p_n \}$ using 
$\{q_1, \cdots , q_n \}$?

I thought we could use linearity of functionals
to show that $\{r_1, \cdots , r_n \} = \{ q_1, \cdots , q_n \}$ (is this correct?) in the following way: if we consider $r_1$ for instance, we should have
$$r_1(p_1 + p_2) = 1 = r_1 (p_1) + r_1(p_2), r_1 (p_2) = 0, \cdots , r_1 (p_n) = 0,$$ so  $r_1 (p_1) = 1$, and $1 = q_1(p_1)$ being a dual basis, so $r_1 = q_1$. Continuing in this way, we would establish $\{r_1, \cdots , r_n \} = \{ q_1, \cdots , q_n \}$. However, considering the $r_1$ case, we also have $q_2(p_2) = 1$, so couldn't we also have $r_1 = q_2$?

Comment: Don't know if I got your question. I understood that $r_1(p_2)=0$ while $q_2(p_2)=1$ and then $r_1\not=q_2$. I tend to agree with your reasoning before 'However'.